# Use login credentials that depends on the URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function created that takes several arguments including:

> url
>   username
>   password
>   downloaded_filename
>   new_filename_name

example code:

```
def reports(url, usr, pass, downloaded_filename, new_filename_name):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('location of webdriver')
    driver get(url)
    usernamebox = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    userbox.send_keys(username)
    ....
```

I use this to log in to several sites and download reports.

But I defined all the above variables to specific names. Is there a way that I can assign this variables to a function so that it is only needed the function name for the variables to be updated? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare them outside of your method body on top of your script if you're sure that you wouldn't need to change them at any instance of you calling your method.

Your sample script would look like:

```
from yourImports import *
# just below your import statements

url = r'https://your_url.com'
usr = 'the_username'
password = 'your password'
downloaded_file_name = r'myFile.txt'
new_file_name = 'my_new_file'

def reports():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('location of webdriver')
    driver get(url)
    usernamebox = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    userbox.send_keys(usr)
    ....
```

> I strongly recommend not using `pass` as a variable name in place for `password` since `pass` is a known `keyword` in python and naming a variable would shadow the keyword **and python interpreter wouldn't allow it**.

**Other approaches:**

1. using a `dictionary` to hold values and using the `keys` to fetch values.
2. using a config text file to store these things and putting them at a directory path so that if you package your code (like an `.exe`) and you want to change these credentials, you can just change the config file.

Comment: `pass` is a keyword, so you can't use it as a variable name anyway. It's a syntax error.

Comment: @kindall yeah I wasn't sure about that one. Thanks for confirming it.